# Injecting style tag + angular component timing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following piece of code:

```
//load theme
await theme.load('light');

$state.go('viewer');
```

theme.load loads a sass file, compiles it, and injects it as a style tag like this:

```
let themeStyles = document.head.querySelector('style#theme');

if(!themeStyles) {
    themeStyles = document.createElement('style');
    themeStyles.setAttribute('id', 'theme');
    document.head.appendChild(themeStyles);
}

themeStyles.textContent = await importer.import('sass/themes/'+theme+'.scss');
```

Here's the template for my viewer state:

```
<map></map>
<top-left-menu></top-left-menu>
<loader></loader>
```

And here's my map component:

```
.component('map', {
    controller: ['$element', MapController]
});

function MapController($element, map) {
    this.$onInit = () => {
        console.log(document.head.querySelector('style#theme').textContent);
        console.log($element[0].getBoundingClientRect())
    }
}
```

The first console log prints the injected CSS as expected, but `getClientBoundingRect()` function is returning width:0 and height:0, even though `$state.go` is only executed after theme.load returns and the css is already injected. I tried $postLink, same thing. Tried replacing the async/await for regular promises (could be some weird babel behaviour), same thing. Only with a ~100ms setTimeout does the element report the correct size.

I wonder if this is related to how styles and the DOM is computed, or to the way angular sets up components. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer - an external font was being loaded through an @import tag so that was delaying the CSS evaluation.